# R for loop through vector and lapply

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I want to create a function that pads zeros no the left until the number is exact 5-digit. For that I’ve created the following function called prefix.

```
prefix <- function(baa) {

        for (i in 1:(5 - nchar(toString(baa)))) {
                    baa <- paste0("0", baa)
        }
        baa
}
```

This function works well with a single integer, but fails to do its job if it receives a vector. My goal is to create a function that will return

```
00001
00012
00123
01234
12345
```

given

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I think this could be easely achieved with lapply, but I havent figuered it out yet. Can you please help?

Comment: why not using `sprintf("%05i",vector)` ?

Comment: @Tensibai - my question is not how to pad, but how to use lapply to do it

Comment: Ô_o just lapply(vec,prefix) but I'm this case sapply would be better (returning a vector instead of a list)...